# Time difference between loading packages using require() and library()

Tags: r, package, require, microbenchmark

Supposedly I want to check the % time differences of loading packages through `library` and `require` functions for each of CRAN packages. I have created the following code.

```
all <- available.packages()[,1]
install.packages(all)

req <- lapply(all, require, character.only = TRUE)
lib <- lapply(all, library, character.only = TRUE)

microbenchmark(req , lib, times = 100)
```

Could you suggest what needs correction?

Comment: You will need to use, for example, `microbenchmark(req = lapply(all, required, character.only = TRUE)`.  Your current code only times how long it takes to print the already existing objects.  But even then this won't give you what you are looking for; the package will get loaded into the search path early, and will alter the behavior of `require` and `library`.  You  need to clear the search path of all packages prior to each iteration.  I don't think `microbenchmark` can do this and identify the time just for loading.  A custom built `for` loop may be necessary.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the motivation behind measuring these time differences?